# wx.Layout for some reason "removes" widgets from panel

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to learn wxPython and stuck with a layout problem. I try to put sets of widgets inside separate panels to manage their position\size in the future. But for some reason code that works fine for "Top block" panel, doesn't work for "Mods" panel.

I googled about Layout() function, but for some reason, it behaves differently in "Top block" and "Mods". Instead of rearranging widgets it just put them all in the thin line on top of the panel. I can't post images, but i can provide screenshoot.

```py
class ItemInfo(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, item, *args):
        super(ItemInfo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.Size = wx.Size(500, 600)

        self.current_item = self.find_current_item(item)
        common_item_types = Storage.ItemStorage.get_common_item_keys()

        # self.Bind(wx.EVT_SHOW, self.show_current_item_stats)
        mod_list = []
        mod_list.append("None")
        for key, value in Storage.item_storage.mod_dict.items():
            mod_list.append(key)

        # Главная панель
        main_panel = wx.Panel(self)
        main_panel.SetBackgroundColour('#484f49')

        ##============================= Шрифты ===============================##

        label_font = wx.Font(16, wx.FONTFAMILY_ROMAN, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, False)
        sublabel_font = wx.Font(12, wx.FONTFAMILY_ROMAN, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, False)
        stat_font = wx.Font(16, wx.FONTFAMILY_ROMAN, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, False)

        # ============================= Заголовок ======================================
        label_panel = wx.Panel(main_panel, pos=(0, 0))
        label_panel.SetSize(500, 30)
        label_panel.SetBackgroundColour('#46f057')
        label_text = wx.StaticText(label_panel, label="Item information")
        label_text.SetFont(label_font)
        label_text.SetForegroundColour('#6b756c')
        label_text.SetPosition((170, 5))


        ##================================ Top block ==========================

        top_panel = wx.Panel(main_panel, pos=(10, 30))
        top_panel.SetSize(470, 70)
        top_panel.SetBackgroundColour('#1271e6')
        top_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        # Создаем коробку с именем предмета
        item_name_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        item_name_label = wx.StaticText(top_panel, label="Current item name")
        item_name_label.SetFont(sublabel_font)
        item_name_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(top_panel, value=self.current_item.name)

        item_name_sizer.AddSpacer(7)
        item_name_sizer.Add(item_name_label, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        item_name_sizer.AddSpacer(5)
        item_name_sizer.Add(item_name_ctrl, wx.EXPAND)
        top_sizer.Add(item_name_sizer, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, border=5)

        # Создаем коробку с типом предмета
        item_key_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        item_key_label = wx.StaticText(top_panel, label="Item key")
        item_key_label.SetFont(sublabel_font)
        item_key_cbox = wx.ComboBox(top_panel, value=self.current_item.key, choices=common_item_types)

        item_key_sizer.AddSpacer(7)
        item_key_sizer.Add(item_key_label, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        item_key_sizer.AddSpacer(5)
        item_key_sizer.Add(item_key_cbox, wx.EXPAND)
        top_sizer.Add(item_key_sizer, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, border=5)

        # Создаем коробку с редкостью предмета
        item_rarity_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        item_rarity_label = wx.StaticText(top_panel, label="Item rarity")
        item_rarity_label.SetFont(sublabel_font)
        item_rarity_cbox = wx.ComboBox(top_panel, value=self.current_item.rarity.key, choices=BaseStats.RARITY_LIST)

        item_rarity_sizer.AddSpacer(7)
        item_rarity_sizer.Add(item_rarity_label, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        item_rarity_sizer.AddSpacer(5)
        item_rarity_sizer.Add(item_rarity_cbox, wx.EXPAND)
        top_sizer.Add(item_rarity_sizer, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, border=5)

        top_panel.SetSizer(top_sizer)
        top_panel.Layout()

        # =============================== Mods ==================================

        mod_panel = wx.Panel(main_panel, pos=(10, 200))
        mod_panel.SetSize(470, 70)
        mod_panel.SetBackgroundColour('#6b756c')
        # mod_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mod_intermediate_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        # Коробка с первым модом
        first_mod_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        first_mod_label = wx.StaticText(mod_panel, label="First mod")
        first_mod_label.SetFont(sublabel_font)
        first_mod_cbox = wx.ComboBox(mod_panel, value=self.current_item.mod_list[0].key, choices=mod_list)

        first_mod_sizer.AddSpacer(7)
        first_mod_sizer.Add(first_mod_label, 0, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        first_mod_sizer.AddSpacer(20)
        first_mod_sizer.Add(first_mod_cbox, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        mod_intermediate_sizer.Add(first_mod_sizer, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, border=5)

        # Коробка со вторым модом
        second_mod_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        second_mod_label = wx.StaticText(mod_panel, label='Second mod')
        second_mod_label.SetFont(sublabel_font)
        second_mod_cbox = wx.ComboBox(mod_panel, value=self.current_item.mod_list[1].key,
                                      choices=mod_list)

        second_mod_sizer.AddSpacer(7)
        second_mod_sizer.Add(second_mod_label, 0, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        second_mod_sizer.AddSpacer(5)
        second_mod_sizer.Add(second_mod_cbox, 0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        mod_intermediate_sizer.Add(second_mod_sizer, 0, flag=wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, border=5)

        mod_panel.SetSizer(mod_intermediate_sizer)
        mod_intermediate_sizer.Layout()
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't call Layout for sizer instead of a panel. But hey, it's funny how you find answers yourself after posting questions +)

Comment: The act of defining the question often provides the answer. :)